# Pick random value by weight php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm about to create "lottary system."

Take a look at my table:

```
userid-lottaryid-amount
1 -------- 1 ----  1
2 -------- 1 ---- 10
3 -------- 1 ---- 15
4 -------- 1 ---- 20
```

I want to choose a winner. and another person for second place.

I just can't select a winner randomly because 4th user has 20 tickets and 1st user has only one.
So I need to generate random results by weight in order to be more fair.

I found php function below but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

```
      function weighted_random_simple($values, $weights){ 
      $count = count($values); 
      $i = 0; 
      $n = 0; 
      $num = mt_rand(0, array_sum($weights)); 

      while($i < $count){
          $n += $weights[$i]; 
          if($n >= $num){
              break; 
          }
          $i++; 
      } 
      return $values[$i]; 

  }

    $values = array('1', '10', '20', '100');
    $weights = array(1, 10, 20, 100);

    echo weighted_random_simple($values, $weights);
```

I must fetch `userid` colomn as array to `$values` and `amount` colomn to `$weights`. But I couln't.

Here is my code so far:

```
    $query = $handler->prepare("SELECT 

      `cvu`.`lottaryid` as `lottaryid`, 
      `cvu`.`userid` as `userid`, 
      `cvu`.`amount` as `amount`, 

      `members`.`id` as `members_memberid`, 
      `members`.`username` as `username`

      FROM `lottariesandmembers` as `cvu`

      LEFT JOIN `members` as `members` ON `cvu`.`userid` = `members`.`id`  WHERE `cvu`.`lottaryid` = 2");
    $query->bindParam(':lottaryid', $lottaryid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();



    while($r = $query->fetch()) {

        for ( $count=1 ; $count <= $r["amount"] ; $count++ ) {

            $abcprint = "$r[userid].$count - $r[username] - <br>";

            echo "$abcprint";

        }


    }
```

This code I have, only lists users as many times as their amount. For example:

```
1.1 user1
2.1 user2
2.2 user2
2.3 user2
..
2.10 user2
3.1 user3
..
3.15 user3
4.1 user4
..
4.20 user4
```

and so on.. But I'm stuck how to pick a winner on that list.

I would like to merge those codes and create this little script, if you would like to help me.

I'm also open for brainstorm if you see the solution on the other way around.

Comment: Do you need to print the list of users * amounts, or is this just a side effect of trying to find the winners?

Comment: side effect. i was thinking i can select winner from that list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing out the values as you are doing, you can just build a large array, and then choose a value randomly from that array.

```
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    for ( $i=0; $i <= $r["amount"]; $i++ ) {
        // Add the user into the array as many times as they have tickets
        $tickets[] = $r['userid'];
    }
}

// select the first place winner
$first = $tickets[mt_rand(0, count($tickets) - 1)];

// remove the first place winner from the array
$tickets = array_values(array_filter($tickets, function($x) use ($first) { 
    return $x != $first; 
}));

// select the second place winner
$second = $tickets[mt_rand(0, count($tickets) - 1)];
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this using math, but I need to think about it a bit more...

Comment: impressive. i'm so close to do what i tried to do whole day. i just echo the `$first` and `$second`. when they return different userid's they are working but some times I'm getting the error `Notice: Undefined offset: 22 in C:\www\lottary\test.php on line 35` instead of `$second`. line 35 is `$tickets = array_filter($tickets, function($x) use ($first) { return $x != $first; });` i didn't understand the `$x` there. can be related with error. thanks a lot again!

Comment: Ah, I forgot that keys are preserved when using array_filter. I think it was because of that. I made a slight edit to fix it using array_values.

Comment: thank you sir. did the trick very well. by the way I just take a look at the arrays by `print_r($tickets);` . and result scared me a little bit I must say :) There are 135 arrays. First one has one value only, second one has two and so on 135th has 135 of them. I am now worried about performance because, i'm testing with total `$amount` number 131. and it's so small. second thing is odds. because until 113th array it's impossible to see 4th user. __thanks a lot, have an upvote :)__

Answer (score 2):

**This isn't very elegant** but should work for smallish lotteries.

It just constructs a massive array and picks an element at random.

Think of having a massive hat full of slips.  Each holder gets their stake in 'slips' and each are labelled with their id.  i.e.  Ten slips with the holder's name 'a', 20 slips with 'b' and so on...

```
<?php

$holder_totals = array(
    'a' => '10',
    'b' => '20',
    'c' => '20',
    'd' => '50'
);

$big_hat = array();
foreach($holder_totals as $holder_id => $total) {
    $holder_hat = array_fill(0, intval($total), $holder_id);
    $big_hat    = array_merge($big_hat, $holder_hat);
}

// Drum roll
foreach (range(1,4) as $n) {
    $random_key = array_rand($big_hat);
    printf("Winner %d is %s.\n", $n, $big_hat[$random_key]);
    unset($big_hat[$random_key]); // Remove winning slip
}
```

Sample output:

```
Winner 1 is d.
Winner 2 is c.
Winner 3 is d.
Winner 4 is b.
```

Big hat looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => a
    [2] => a
    [3] => a
    [4] => a
    [5] => a
    [6] => a
    [7] => a
    [8] => a
    [9] => a
    [10] => b
    [11] => b
    [12] => b
    [13] => b
    [14] => b
    ... and so on...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  /**
   * getRandomWeightedElement()
   * Utility function for getting random values with weighting.
   * Pass in an associative array, such as array('A'=>5, 'B'=>45, 'C'=>50)
   * An array like this means that "A" has a 5% chance of being selected, "B" 45%, and "C" 50%.
   * The return value is the array key, A, B, or C in this case.  Note that the values assigned
   * do not have to be percentages.  The values are simply relative to each other.  If one value
   * weight was 2, and the other weight of 1, the value with the weight of 2 has about a 66%
   * chance of being selected.  Also note that weights should be integers.
   * 
   * @param array $weightedValues
   */
  function getRandomWeightedElement(array $weightedValues) {
    $rand = mt_rand(1, (int) array_sum($weightedValues));

    foreach ($weightedValues as $key => $value) {
      $rand -= $value;
      if ($rand <= 0) {
        return $key;
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is an efficient and flexible function. But You have to modify it if you want to use non-integer weighting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use weightedChoice function from my library [nspl](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#nsplrnd).

```
use function \nspl\rnd\weightedChoice;

// building your query here

$pairs = [];
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    $pairs[] = [$r['userid'], $r['amount']];
}

$winnerId = weightedChoice($pairs);
```

You can install the library with composer:

```
composer require ihor/nspl
```

Or you can simply reuse weightedChoice code from GitHub:

```
/**
 * Returns a random element from a non-empty sequence of items with associated weights
 *
 * @param array $weightPairs List of pairs [[item, weight], ...]
 * @return mixed
 */
function weightedChoice(array $weightPairs)
{
    if (!$weightPairs) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Weight pairs are empty');
    }

    $total = array_reduce($weightPairs, function($sum, $v) { return $sum + $v[1]; });
    $r = mt_rand(1, $total);

    reset($weightPairs);
    $acc = current($weightPairs)[1];
    while ($acc < $r && next($weightPairs)) {
        $acc += current($weightPairs)[1];
    }

    return current($weightPairs)[0];
}
```